# What is Paper Weight?

Tags: paper, terminology

I also see a weight associated with the art paper I buy.

For example: 
I have Bristol Board that is marked 100lbs, Pastel Paper marked 98lb, Sketch Paper marked 50lbs, etc.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The weight is the weight of a ream (500 sheets) in the unit of uncut size, which varies with the stock type (see [here](https://www.oki.com/us/printing/support/understanding-paper-weight/), for example).

A more consistent measure of paper weight is the grams per sq metre value (gsm) which is what it says, the mass of 1 square metre of the paper, which is the area density of the paper.

Comment: As a reference, standard copy paper is 80 gsm, 120-160 gsm is thick paper, 300 gsm is cardboard or thick watercolor paper while tissue paper can be around 40-60 gsm. These are approximate ratings, so actual weight of a square meter of two paper types both rated 80 gsm may actually differ. Still, these rating offer some idea of whether you are dealing with thin tissue or thick cardboard.